# what does the ":=" operator do in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have come across some scripts that use ":=" instead of  "=" for assignments, what is the difference. I have tried looking it V5 reference but it does not seem to be there

Thanks

Comment: ':=' is a re assignment, not an assignment, it presumes the variable already has history, and it may have history if you use var my_variable=0. for example. var is executed once on the first bar of the data set. So my_variable:= my_variable+some_number  means add some_number to the last known value of my_variable (which is like my_variable[1]). Shorthand same thing is my_variable+=some_number.

Comment: If you don't use a var call, then you can also do my_variable=0.0 in some prior line and then re-assign with my_variable:=xxx in a line later in your script. The difference here is that for each bar, my_variable will be set to 0.0 first before re-assignment.  whereas with var it is only set to 0.0 once. self referencing will be different. In the second example, my_variable := my_variable + some_number will use the value of my_variable=0.0 in the prior script line, not the historical reference.

Comment: These are fantastic explanations, Thank you!